# Read accented characters in C

Tags: c

I need to read a text file which contains accented letters such as 'ã' and 'é'
I've manage to read normal letters with this code

```
while (cha != EOF)
{
    ch = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    cha = tolower(getchar());
    int i = 0;  
    while(((cha > 64) && (cha <91)) || ((cha > 96) && (cha <123)))
    {
        ch[i] = cha;
        i++;
        putchar(cha);
        printf("\n");
        cha = tolower(getchar());
    };
}
```

Put I still need to read the accented letters

Comment: This is not really related to "multi-character character constants" at all. "Multi-character character constant" is a language feature that does not appear in your code in any way, shape or form.

Comment: That is the error that I get on the terminal warning: multi-character character constant

Comment: Which specific line of code produces this message? (Note, BTW, that this is not an error.)

Comment: On my system, the accented characters are encoded as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). So, for example `Ä` is encoded as two bytes: `0xC3` followed by `0x84`.

Comment: You mean this error: http://ideone.com/cmCtS9 ? That's because 'ñ' doesn't fit in a byte (if encoded in UTF-8, which is likely the case). But nowhere in the code in your question is there a character constant, never mind a character constant with a non-ascii character.

Comment: The solution depends on how the text is encoded.  At least be sure to use `int cha`.

Comment: Note that the semicolon after the close brace of the while loop is a superfluous empty statement and not a requirement of the language.

Comment: The posted code contains numerous 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  The 'magic' numbers are: 50, 64, 91, 96, 123.  Suggest 1) for the numbers that are representative of ascii characters, to use the actual characters, like `'a'`  and for other numbers to use an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: when calling any of the 'heap' allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: it is a bad idea to assume that there will be 50 or less characters to be read before encountering EOF.  An input of greater than 50 characters will result in overflow of the allocated memory.  That results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249 My previous comment included a link to the [UTF-8 page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

Comment: The C standard doesn’t have a solid support for accented letters. There are many encodings and each one need different answer.

Comment: @user3386109,  Your right, I was thinking ASCII, not UTF8

Comment: Each pass through the 'while()' loop results in another memory allocation (AND overlays the pointer to the prior memory allocation.)  This results in a massive memory leak.   At the very least, pass the pointer to `free()` at the end of the loop.   However, if the buffer is defined as `wchar`, then no call to `malloc()` needed and no `i` variable needed

Comment: the inner `while()` loop will never be exited after it is entered.  Perhaps you meant to use a `if()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

since the UTF8 characters are multibyte items,

the posted code should be using:

```
 getwchar() rather than getchar()
 putwchar() rather than putchar() 
 towlower() rather than tolower()
 sizeof(wchar) rather than sizeof(char)
```